Unreal engine export fbx with light intensity from level sequence
How to just export the light I animated to blender as I have to blend the two renders together with same light-intensity animation?

Are you using Unreal version 4 or 5? It's a bit confusing when multiple versions are tagged. If you want to export fbx files to Blender, consider including the fbx and Blender tags instead of doubling-up on Unreal tags.

Lights generally cannot be imported from Blender into Unreal.
The positional animation can come through as a skeletal animation object.
However, light-intensity animation values cannot be directly imported, since the implementation in Blender is shader specific.

Universal Scene Description USD format is a good stepping point, but it is as of 2024, still incomplete.
The main challenges are the various shader languages and cross platform support.
